# How to layout application icons in the panel?

Tags: gnome-panel, icons

Application and applets icons are changing their position or even disappears from the gnome-panel (see an example).

[image]

It often happens after connecting to external monitor with different resolution setting, or sometimes happens by chance (I don't know what is the reason of such behaviour). Some icons I can move, others I can't. I don't know if they're locked or not.
My question is:

- Is there any settings/software for icon's position control in the panel? I noticed that locking does not resolve this issue.

Thank you for support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These icons are a few different things:

- [image]

  1. The Notification area
  2. The Indicator applet (all the icons are in one single panel applet)
  3. The Clock
  4. The Session Indicator

Those are all panel applets. They are little programs that display on the panel. You can move them around like so:

- [image]

Right click and un-check *Lock To Panel*, then right click again and select *Move*. You may need to unlock them all to move one after the others.

Note: right-clicking the notification area will bring up the context-menu of the icon you've clicked. To get it's menu, right click on the little grabbing area on the left of it:

[image]

You can check if your panel will look alright after rebooting by forcing it to restart:

```
killall gnome-panel
```

Or, if you want to get back to the original configuration, undoing all your changes (that is *all the changes you have **ever** made*):

```
mv ~/.gconf/apps/panel ~/gnome-panel-backup
killall gnome-panel
```

Open a Terminal via *Applications → Accessories → Terminal* to enter those commands.

Comment: Dear Stefano, as you see I have a set of 6 icons (to the right starting from Bluetooth manager which I cannot move along the panel :) All these icons have no 'move' option in context menu. /grazie per la correzione della mia domanda :)/

Comment: Vincenzo: The little grabbing area to the left of those icons is where you can right click to move them. It's barely visible, but there are three little black lines to the left of the bluetooth icon. This is where you grab the Notification Area (it's tiny!) - Hope this helps!

Comment: I've added a screen shot to point it out. You may have to click it a few times, there is a small bug that sometimes you don't quite hit it, if you are not pixel-perfect with the mouse. It seems like you have to hit one of the lines *exactly* :)